# sent the query to data base for every one minute

Tags: java, mysql, database, google-maps, jsp

i working with google map Api in my java application.in this i need to send the query to database for every one minute and delete the records(locations info) automatically. i used jsp to delete the records,i want call this jsp file for every one minute.this jsp file deleted the records perfectly if i executed externally on the project,

```
delete markers.jsp

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%!Connection connection;
   Statement statement;
   ResultSet rs;
   PreparedStatement preparedStatement;
    %>
    <%
    ArrayList<Object> arrayList = new ArrayList<Object>(); 
    String query1="select sno,time,date_time from jam_info";
    connection=DBCreation.getConnection();
    statement=connection.createStatement();
    rs=statement.executeQuery(query1);
    while(rs.next())
    {
        int sno=rs.getInt(1);
        int expectedtime=rs.getInt(2);
        Timestamp timeReg = rs.getTimestamp(3);
        long time_minutes=(timeReg.getTime()/1000)/60;
        long total_time=expectedtime+time_minutes;
        System.out.println("expected time"+expectedtime);
        System.out.println("record insert time"+timeReg);
        System.out.println("time minutes inminutes"+(timeReg.getTime()/1000)/60);
        System.out.println("totaltime"+total_time);
        long currentTime = (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000)/60;
        System.out.println("now"+currentTime);

        if(total_time<currentTime)
        {
            preparedStatement=connection.prepareStatement("delete from jam_info where sno=?");
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, sno);
            int res=preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
            if(res>0)
            {
                System.out.println(res+"deleted");
            }
        }

    }
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

with this record i can delete the record based on my requirement,but how can i use this jsp file for every one minute to hit the server

Comment: If you can do it server-side, look at [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). A built-in feature of Java to run a [Runnable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) every x minutes you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send a ajax call using timer..

```
<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);
function myTimer()
{
var d=new Date();
var t=d.toLocaleTimeString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=t;
}
function myStopFunction()
{
clearInterval(myVar);
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanku for u response,its fine,but how can i use deletemarkers.jsp in this code,because i have to delete record from data base,

Comment: Is there any special reason you doing it via a JSP ? If you want you can use Quartz Scheduler for this too

Comment: i dont know how to work with Quartz Scheduler,is it possible to use my deletemarkers.jsp logic by using Quartz Scheduler,will u please modify it with Quartz Scheduler other wise i will do ,thanks for u r reply

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform a action at particular interval time, you can use Quartz Scheduler. If you want the opeartions to be triggered from UI, use Jquery's setTimeout or setInterval and call your custom method to do anything.

Comment: can u please explain with example

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule it through crontab, if you don't have its privileges then ask your system admin or dba-

open cron file by below command;

crontab -e

go to last line and press small 'o' : it will move you in insert mode and create a new line.

paste below line here:

*/1 * * * * /usr/......./bin/java -jar /..path.../my_file.jar

press esc key then : "semicolon" then type wq then press enter : it will save above line and exit from file.

which will be executed after every 1 minute interval and execute whatever will be in file.